# Linq query to get the distinct values in a list

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

Suppose this is my member class

```
class Member 
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string MemberName { get; set; }
    public int Distance { get; set; }
}
```

And, this is list.

```
var list = new List<Member>();
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "01", MemberName="andy" Distance=3});
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "02", MemberName="john" Distance=5});
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "01", MemberName="mathew" Distance=7});
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "03", MemberName="bakara" Distance=2});
```

Can anyone please suggest the logic/ linq query to get the List having distinct/unique categoryID with Shortest distance.

The `output` should be :

```
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "01", MemberName="andy" Distance=3});
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "02", MemberName="john" Distance=5});
list.Add(new { CategoryId = "03", MemberName="bakara" Distance=2});
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should cover your needs:

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(item => item.CategoryId);
var shortest = grouped.Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(item => item.Distance).First());
```

It first groups the items with the same `CategoryId`, then selects the first from each group (ordered by `Distance`).

---

**Update:** 
You could chain all of these together too, if you prefer:

```
var shortest = list.GroupBy(item => item.CategoryId)
                   .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(item => item.Distance)
                   .First());
```

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to those above, however it is technically a one liner for those interested....

```
var queryResult= (from l in list
                  select new Member()
                 { 
                    CategoryId = l.CategoryId , 
                    MemberName = l.MemberName 
                    Distance = l.Distance
                 }).GroupBy(x=>x.CatagoryId).Select(z=>z.OrderBy(i=>i.Distance).First()).ToList();
```

Comment: thank you so much , for posting this one, it helped me after hours of research, i was just trying to display all duplicate records in EF but when i ordered by Id it works , appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

Group the list into categories, then order each grouping by distance, taking the first item (the lowest distance). Project the results into a new `Member` collection.

```
var query = from member in list 
            group member by member.CategoryId into memberGrouping
            let groupedMember = memberGrouping.OrderBy (mg => mg.Distance).First() 
            select new Member()
            { 
              CategoryId = memberGrouping.Key, 
              MemberName = groupedMember.MemberName, 
              Distance = groupedMember.Distance 
            };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
List<Member> sourceList = new List<Member>();
IEnumerable<Member> result = 
    (sourceList as IEnumerable<Member>)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(value => value.CategoryId);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var distinctIds = list.Distinct(item => item.CategoryId).ToList();
var newList = new List<Member>();
foreach(var id in distinctIds){
      newList.Add(list.Where(item => item.CategoryId == id).Min(item => item.Distance))
}
newList.OrderBy(item => item.CategoryId);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Member {
    public string CategoryId {get; set;}
    public string MemberName{get; set;}
    public int Distance{get; set;}
}

var list = new List<Member>();
list.Add(new Member{ CategoryId = "01", MemberName="andy", Distance=3});
list.Add(new Member{ CategoryId = "02", MemberName="john", Distance=5});
list.Add(new Member{ CategoryId = "01", MemberName="mathew", Distance=7});
list.Add(new Member{ CategoryId = "03", MemberName="bakara", Distance=2});

var query = list.GroupBy(member => member.CategoryId).Select(x=>x.OrderBy(y=>y.Distance).First());
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works, if you do not require items ordered by (little modified [Kjartan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20883982/698127))

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(item => item.CategoryId).ToList();
var shortest = grouped.Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(item => item.Distance).First());
```