# Remove duplicate from large lists efficiently?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a list which contains ids and values and I need to remove ids duplication.  I am looking for an efficiently way  preferable in LINQ, instead of my loop and if condition.  Thank you for any help and advise.

```
var list = new List<Tuple<int, double>>();

Current values:
1, 3.6
1, 3.8
2, 5.6
3, 8.1

Wished values:
1, 3.6
2, 5.6
3, 8.1


for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (list[i].Item1 == list[i + 1].Item1)
        list.RemoveAt(i+ 1);
}
```

Comment: there is no difference in current and wished values

Comment: Look now, I just noticed after post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20883890/linq-query-to-get-the-distinct-values-in-a-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406242/select-distinct-using-linq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998066/linq-distinct-values

Comment: I have to comment on this.. (probably will become my pet peeve on LINQ related questions like these on SO). Why do you think that LINQ version is more efficient compared to the simple for loop implementation? As far as **execution efficiency** is concerned, the accepted answer, which uses `.GroupBy`, `.Select` and `.ToDictionary` is far from being efficient. :( So what efficiency do you seek here? I do not understand. Please clarify.. I am very curious.

Comment: @VikasGupta some people use LINQ because want shorter better readable and maintainable code.  I hope this satisfy your curiosity.  However, I think would be batter if you could help instead of been curious.

Comment: `IEqualityComparer<T>` interface defines methods to support the comparison of objects for equality. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your opinion that LINQ is generally more readable / maintainable and is generally equitable to efficiency, I present the following solution, which uses LINQ, and (IMHO compared to others presented so far) is more efficient in execution as well -

```
list = list.Where((entry, i) => i == 0 || entry.Item1 != list[i - 1].Item1).ToList();
```

Comment: This is in addition to my original question, there is any way that list = ... containd just ids (only item1)?

Comment: `var list2 = list.Select(item => item.Item1).Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: @Vikas - Your solution is great, but if you only ever check the previous element, you might need to sort the list first (if the list is not already sorted). `list = list.OrderBy(item => item.Item1).ToList();`

Comment: @Corak Agreed.. but I think the example stated in the question (along with current implementation with for loop) clearly suggests that following assumptions can be made for this specific scenario - 1. It is a list (specifically, supports indexing, otherwise indexer cannot be used). 2. List is already sorted. 3. Object type in the list doesn't already implement appropriate Comparer / Equatable, there are many :(, interface to support the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

If Id and Values are same as the other one. It will remove that item from list.

```
distinctList = list.Distinct().ToList();
```

If you are okay with converting the ***Tuple*** to ***Dictionary***:

**Try This:** If Only `Id`'s  are duplicate removes that item from list. It will not consider the value duplication.

```
var distinctDictionary = list.GroupBy(id => id.Item1)
                         .Select(group => group.First())
                         .ToDictionary(id => id.Item1, val => val.Item2);
```

**Look at the Screen shots:**

**Solution 1:**

[image: Solution One]

**Solution 2:**

[image: Solution Two]

Comment: It compares only the Ids or the entire row?

Comment: Only the Ids, without considering the values.

Comment: For Ex: If `Id and Values are same` as the other one. It will remove that item from list.

Comment: Where as Second Solution will work only based on the `Id` duplication.

Comment: Ok, but just the Ids are the same, values are different.  See my example.  Anyway, in my read application I only need Ids, what if I use your second example (distinctDictionary) and then convert distinctDictionary into list taking just the Ids?

Comment: Check out my screen shots. Rather explaining somthing just visualize it. :)

Comment: In my example I have 1 3.6 and 1 3.8.  I only need one of them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65264/discussion-between-doro-and-rjk).

Comment: I am at work and some security policy does not allow me to access the chart.

Comment: Anyway, in your code I am see that you have 1 3.6 and again 1 3.6 while I have 1 3.6 and 1 3.8.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you a `List` with tuples? With the requested functionality I would use a `Dictionary` so you won't have duplicates.

Comment: It is just an example.  In my case I have Dates a function has interpolate them.

Comment: @doro - From what you provided, it seems like you have one "identifying" piece of data and then "something else", too. In the code you showed, the "identifying" piece of data is the `Item1` of the tuple and "something else" is `Item2`. In this case it's `int` and `double`, but it could also be `long` and `DateTime`, or `Guid` and `SomeHugeClass`. Now you have a list of those pairs and you want to "remove duplicates" from it. Basically you only want *one* "something else" for each "identifying" thing. This is `key -> value` and this is, what `Dictionaries` are made for.

Comment: I just explained why I am using List<tuple>.  But, the point is how to remove ids duplication.  I also included a loop and if which does the work but I am searching a better way.

Answer (score 0):

DistinctByKey = list.Select(x => x.Keys).Distinct();

DistinctByValue= DistinctByKey.Select(x => x.Values).Distinct();